# Indicatorview for ELCImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, image, ipad, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a UIActivityIndicator to a modal view (ELCimagepicker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160847/adding-a-uiactivityindicator-to-a-modal-view-elcimagepicker)

How we can integrate indicatorview to the ELCImagePickerController. I am having hard time to do that. I referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160847/adding-a-uiactivityindicator-to-a-modal-view-elcimagepicker) too but it has no answer. I put comment there too for posting integrated code but no luck yet..

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figure out your problem. You can do this as below..

```
-(void)selectedAssets:(NSArray*)_assets {

ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate * appDelegate = (ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(appDelegate.window.frame.size.width/2, appDelegate.window.frame.size.height/2);
[activityIndicator setHidden:NO];
[activityIndicator setTag:1001];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:activityIndicator];
[appDelegate.window bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];

[self performSelector:@selector(doProcess:) withObject:_assets afterDelay:2.1];
}


- (void) doProcess:(NSArray *)_assets {

NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for(ALAsset *asset in _assets) {

    NSMutableDictionary *workingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [workingDictionary setObject:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"];
    [workingDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [workingDictionary setObject:[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:[[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

    [returnArray addObject:workingDictionary];

    [workingDictionary release];    
}

[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(elcImagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)]) {
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(elcImagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) withObject:self withObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:returnArray]];
}

}
```

After all that when you want to remove activity indicator. can write below code.

```
ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate *app = (ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[app.window viewWithTag:1001] removeFromSuperview];
```

Let me know if this answer help you ...

Thanks,

Minesh Purohit